# WebSocket doesn't work in IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, websocket

I hope you can help me.
I tried to run WebSocket example from Tomcat (tomcat_dir\webapps\examples\websocket) and works fine when I start Tomcat manually, without Intellij IDEA. Then I moved *echo.xhtml* and *EchoAnnotation.java* to my IDEA project, and in fails. I get "Info: WebSocket connection closed, Code: 1006". And it says "Class 'echoAnnotation' is never used" so I think tomcat can't see it in current conditions. How can I fix it?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to create a new project, and mark "WebSockets" at the first screen.
**UPDATE**
The solution above is incorrect, it stops working a few minutes after creating project(magic). The right way to fix this is to use TomEE instead Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

I know am late for the party. I've also faced the same problem. I am using **Intellij IDEA 14.1.3**. I've solved the problem by removing the **web-socket-api.jar** from the artifacts. The problem in the project structure shouldn't be solved (**Artifact '[Your-module-name]:war exploded': library 'websocket-api' required for module '[Your-module-name]' is missing from the artifact [Fix]**). The problem should exist there. You shouldn't fix. That's how i solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

trying to use with `<scope>provided</scope>` or like in previous post